# pandas DataFrame - find max between offset columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe given by

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,2))
df

    0           1
0   0.264053    -1.225456
1   0.805492    -1.072943
2   0.142433    -0.469905
3   0.758322    0.804881
4   -0.281493   0.602433
```

I want to return a Series object with 4 rows, containing `max(df[0,0], df[1,1]), max(df[1,0], df[2,1]), max(df[2,0], df[3,1]), max(df[3,0], df[4,1])`. More generally, what is the best way to compare the max of column `0` and column `1` offset by `n` rows?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply `max` to rows after having shifted the first column.

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, 0].shift(), df.iloc[:, 1]], axis=1).apply(max, axis=1).dropna()
```

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a dedicated function to deal with this...pandas never disappoints!